# How to change build multiple file version? my app is not working for this issue

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, build

My project is clean. I bought it from codecanyon. Now I want to change the api version 23 to 28. Below I've shared two gradle files that need to change api level version 23 to 28 for playstore purpose. How can I change this? I need to edit my Gradle and replace the version 23 to 28 and comment the code.

gradle.build (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile project(':InitActivity')
}
```

gradle.build (InitActivity)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I've edited your question to fix two problems: (1) ASAP begging;  (2) a fairly clear request for free labour. Please bear in mind that this is a volunteer community, which means (1) people help you at their leisure, and other people's questions are important to them too; (2) people want to help _you_ to do the work, not do it for you. We can recommend some freelancer sites if you need someone to undertake the work.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the lines with targetSdkVersion to 28 in both files and update the compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion lines to 28.X.X after updating the SDK tools to 28

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.1 and Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:28.0.1

Comment: so? don't need to change them?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:28+' and compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28+' is this correct?

Comment: Update you SDK tools first and change the versions accordingly. Then change  targetSdkVersion compileSdkVersion buildToolsVersion fields to 28 depending on the versions found in SDK tools